# Clojure: Transform string into key-value pairs in hash-map

Tags: string, clojure, hashmap

I'll start with my test using the [speclj](http://speclj.com) framework.

```
(it "turns the string into a hash-map"
  (should= {1 "1" 2 "2" 3 "3"}
    (format-string "1=1 2=2 3=3")))
```

Then my code:

```
(:use [clojure.string :only (split)])

(defn format-string [string]
  (split string #"\s+"))
```

Right now, the `format-string` function returns `["1=1" "2=2" "3=3"]` and the test fails.  As you can see in my test, I want it to return a hash-map with key-value pairs indicated by the `=` sign.

I've tried a few things and I've gotten close, but can't quite understand how to make this transformation.

***EDIT***

Figured out one solution, although the keys are strings instead of integers.

My code:

```
(defn format-board [route]
  (let [[first second third] (split route #"\s+")]
    (merge 
      (apply hash-map (split-at-equals first))
      (apply hash-map (split-at-equals second))
      (apply hash-map (split-at-equals third))
```

This returns `{"1" "1" "2" "2" "3" "3"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have split at the spaces, but then you need to split again at the `=` delimiter. You can use regular expressions to do the parsing. Once you have your pairs you can `assoc` into a hash-map. Here I've used `reduce` to effect the transformation.

```
user=> (reduce #(assoc % (read-string (nth %2 1)) (nth %2 2)) {} 
   #_>   (re-seq #"([^=\s]+)=([^=\s]+)" "1=1 2=2 3=3") )
{3 "3", 2 "2", 1 "1"}
```

Note key order is not applicable to hash-maps

```
user=> (= {1 "1", 2 "2", 3 "3"} *1)
true
```

Comment: Thanks - I edited my question to include the solution I wrote, but it's not quite there. Yours worked, although I'm working to modify it to be more extensible. For example, what if the string contained more pairs, like 4=4 5=5 6=6, etc.?

Comment: @rzv This would work for any number of pairs. For example, try  `(reduce #(assoc % (read-string (nth %2 1)) (nth %2 2)) {}
  (re-seq #"([^=\s]+)=([^=\s]+)" "1=1 2=2 3=3 4=4 5=5 :foo=6 :bar=7"))`

Comment: Ah, great! You are correct, that works well. Could you by chance walk me through what's happening there?  It's a bit terse.

Comment: @rsv I could expound later, but you can explore this in the REPL. Just start with the innermost form, see what it does, experiment, and move outward. I suspect though that you are missing the power of `reduce`, which should be one of your top go-to tools. See http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/08/reduce-not-scary.html.

Comment: Nice usage of `re-seq`, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the potential parallel version using `clojure.core.reducers`:

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])
(require '[clojure.string :as s])

(def string-of-pairs "1=1 2=2 3=3 4=4")

; reducing fn to convert seq of (key, value) to hash-map
(defn rf ([] {}) ([acc [k v]] (assoc acc k v)))

; for large colls, fold will parallelize execution
(r/fold merge rf (r/map #(s/split % #"=") (s/split string-of-pairs #"\s+")))
```

For better understanding of reducers, watch [this video](http://vimeo.com/45561411) where
Rich explains motivation behind reducers and demonstrates some usage.